# Kotlin flow that emits only new values to subscribers and keeps it last value in cache

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Is it possible to create an equivalent of `LiveEvent` with Kotlin `Flow`, i.e. new subscribers receive only new values and the possibility to access the last emitted value?

Similare to

```
MutableSharedFlow(
    extraBufferCapacity = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST
)
```

but with possibility to access the extra buffer value?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `StateFlow`

Comment: nope. stateflow emits current value to new subscribers

Comment: There is no version of Flow that does what you're describing. And Google doesn't recommend SingleLiveEvent either because of some issues I don't remember. They recommend a Flow or LiveData around a mutable class where you can mutate a property to mark it as "handled".

Comment: Maybe a `StateFlow`, but when subscribing use: `stateFlow.drop(1)`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. But note that your use case is strange: You *don't* want to be notified of the initial value, but you *do* want to access it.

Comment: the `drop(1)` solution fits the needs. thanks!